# Which type should I use for property of instance in typescript?

Tags: typescript, types

I have instance of class `Foo`.

And I would like to print `hi` property from `string` variable like:

```
class Foo {
    hi() { console.log('hi') }
}

const instance = new Foo();

const go = (field: string): void => instance[field]()

go('hi')
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=9&ssc=9&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8CwAoAkACwJYAoBKFaYeAOwnhAFMA6EeAc3wHI9XiBfDH9DMpQAu0XMLDlgNaAF5o5GgHc4iIgG4MAihBFMkc-ADNcNEABMAXNB0AnMU0JWAbvFxnZAPlHjJNANrGpmYAukSa6HpsHIRAA

Which type must be `property` variable? It is not string by typescript.

Error:

> type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type Foo

Comment: there is no error. this code is perfectly valid

Comment: What's the problem exactly? Code works successfully!

Comment: Ok, my bad, see updated example code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all we should to make sure that property name is callable. Imagine situation, where you have an instance with mixed properties. Callable and not.

```js
class Foo {
    notCallable = 10
    hi() { console.log('hi') }
}

const instance = new Foo();


type Fn = (...args: any[]) => any

type Callable<T> = {
    [Prop in keyof T]: T[Prop] extends Fn ? Prop : never
}[keyof T]

type Test = Callable<typeof instance> // 'hi'
```

As you might have noticed, `Callable` returns only callable properties.

Let's apply our restirction to the function:

```js
class Foo {
    notCallable = 10
    hi() { console.log('hi') }
}

const instance = new Foo();


type Fn = (...args: any[]) => any

type Callable<T> = {
    [Prop in keyof T]: T[Prop] extends Fn ? Prop : never
}[keyof T]

type Test = Callable<typeof instance> // 'hi'


const call = <Obj,>(inst: Obj) =>
    <Key extends Callable<Obj>>(key: Key) =>
        inst[key]();

const applyObject = call(instance);

const callMethod = applyObject('hi')
```

Try to provide any other prop than `hi` to `applyObject`, TS will throw an error

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.0-beta#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8CwAoAkAO3gFwGEwRwAjEAU2gF5oBGABg0wAsBLACgEoVph5sEeJQB0IeAHMOAcnbSeAXwxL0GfoLzQ2GsNmBVa2CgHc4ibgG4M19HgCeAByqxsNaBxGewAJwkQAXNC6dgDaALo81AB8Qdh2NvZO0EQkYOQUADwAKjG0aFghAAre8A5argDWFHbwAGbQWWGBWUUlDmHQFAAeeBTYACYwLtAA-NDFpdCBRgBuFN7KIVU19Y0JjlRZFBCatClklBmJFHXlO7r6MQD0V9CybNI2agI7fMQgbhkA8qQAVgA0UQ42h2gR%20v0iUWYGQA0tVOj0%20oNku80odwVEgctAnC7JDmJgQXgltUwpYbOpXmAHA4QHZwRRgLs3iRgTo9BQuFZVOhKZpgO8ALIUPAseD9NzU2n0v6MvAyORcIA)

Answer (score 0):

`field` is `typeof` 'hi' because it's the property of Foo. Actually this approach for calling with this structure isn't good. You want exactly the `field`. For a thousands of properties you can use `keyof` from the `Foo` class. Here's the code:

```
   class Foo {
    hi() { console.log('hi') }
    bye() { console.log('bye') }
}

const instance = new Foo();

const go = (field: keyof Foo): void => instance[field]()

go('bye')//success
go('hi')//success
go('anything else')//failed
```

[Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8CwAoAkACwJYAoBKFaYeAOwnhAFMA6EeAc3wHI9XiBfDTAIwCeNIiTKVq9Ri1aCanaD3SKMYiABdouSmrDlgNaAF5o5GgHc4iIgG4MKiuuhMkx-ADNcNEABMAXNABrGgF4N0t4Qn8AN3hcbyMAPk1tXX0AbQ8vbwBdIjt0ZzZZTgxC9lxOIA)

Comment: Ok, how can I do it for object with thousand of properties?